# Are there possible solutions that solves both Laplace $\nabla^2 u=0$ and the Wave equations $\nabla^2 u=\ddot{u}/c^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Are there possible solutions that solves both Laplace $\nabla^2 u=0$ and the Wave equations $\nabla^2 u=\frac{\ddot{u}}{c^2}$?

I would like to know which consequences have for a function if its solves at the same time the Laplace equation as the Wave equation:

- If the function is real-valued?
- If the function is complex-valued?
- Does these solutions fulfill the [Kramers–Kronig relations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations)?

Comment: Did you mean to have $\nabla^2u$ on the left-hand side of both equations? If so, the most general solution is $u=v+tw$ for $v,\,w$ time-independent solutions of Laplace's equation.

Comment: Is this not equivalent to solving $\frac{\ddot{u}}{c^2} = 0$ i.e. $u(\mathbf{x}, t) = A(\mathbf{x})t + B(\mathbf{x})$, so $t\nabla^2 A + \nabla^2 B = 0$? Thus, we just require $A$, $B$ to be harmonic.

Comment: @J.G. + SharkyKesa  thanks for commenting.  Both have give the same solution, but I am not sure if it works for complex function since they have to fulfill also the [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) in order to be differentiable... Could you elaborate on this issue on an answer please?... Also, It is possible to have [singular solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution) in the time variable which also solves the equations but aren't of the form you have commented?

Comment: Since $t$ is real, $v+tw$ satisfies that condition at all $t$ iff $v,\,w$ both do. As for singular solutions, I think the Picard–Lindelöf theorem implies there are none.